# WCF service handle server responce on the server

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm working with WCF and what I want is: 
Client makes request to the server. Server all done and is going to response to the client.
But communication with client is dead (network problem for eg.). How can I handle response on the server side and for eg. log network problem.

Above all I want to handle timeout and communication exceptions while sending back the response from server, and handle it not only on client but on the **server**. I assume that I need to interact with wcf infrastructure or smth like that, smth that sends response.

Comment: You implement the [`IErrorHandler` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) and "log" messages to where you want to have them. Other than that, please provide more details, code, what you have tried so far, etc.

Comment: I can handle exceptions with FaultExceptions either. The problem is: how can I catch communication and timeout exceptions on server side.

Comment: That is what the `IErrorHandler` can do. It hooks into the (server-side) WCF stack and can intercept errors, that you usercode cannot. Please read up on it.

Comment: Thanks for help, now I know how to implement it.